# How to assign middleware partially to Laravel resource routes?

Tags: laravel

How can I assign auth middleware to parts of Resource Route?

This code is the resource route for the posts

```
Route::apiResource('posts', PostController::class);
```

which can be interpreted as follows

```
Route::get('posts', [PostController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('posts/create', [PostController::class, 'create']);
Route::get('posts/{id}', [PostController::class, 'show']);
Route::get('posts/{id}/edit', [PostController::class, 'edit']);
Route::post('posts', [PostController::class, 'store']);
Route::put('posts/{id}', [PostController::class, 'update']);
Route::delete('posts/{id}', [PostController::class, 'destroy']);
```

I want to assign auth middleware only to `destroy` method or `store`, `update`, etc, etc.

Is there any way I can stick with `Route::apiResource('posts', PostController::class);` yet parts of routes are assigned auth middleware?

Comment: You can assign middlewares in your controller's constructor

Comment: If I use controller constructor, all methods can be used when authorized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by calling `middleware` method in `__construct()` method of your `PostController`

Bind middleware with only ... methods:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth')
        ->only([
            'destroy',
            'store',
            'update',
        ]);
}
```

or bind to all methods except ... :

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth')
        ->except([
            'show',
            'index',
        ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your controller constructor

```
  public function __construct()
    {
        
        $this->middleware('auth', ['only' => ['destroy ']]);
    }
```

This will only apply auth middleware to destory method.

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#controller-middleware

Answer (score 0):

you need to use gates that's exactly the purpose of it , to allow or disallow some actions
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization

like you said if you use middleware , u ll allow or disallow all .